# Declare "variable variables" or "dynamic variables" from array values?

Tags: c#, variables

I am making a csv reader for game data loading in C# and all I want to do is 
to declare a variable from the value of an array(variables) which we can do in php like $$foo.
Like

```
void csvReader(string s)
{
   string[] vars = s.split(',');
   foreach(string var in vars)
   {
       // I want to create a variable with the name of the value
       string[] var = new string[10];
   }
}
```

Comment: See [`Dictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [dotnetperls Dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary) entry.

Comment: you can only do this in scripting languages like php because they are not compiled. The C# compiler has to know what it should do with your variable, and so you can't define it at runtime.

Comment: @RedAlert, PHP has been JIT-compiled since PHP 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to dynamically create local variables.  To map a string to some value that you associate with that string (in this case, a string array) you can use a `Dictionary`.  Use the value that you're reading in as the key, and then you can set the value to be your string array and access that array through the dictionary's indexer.

Comment: [Well...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.localbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) but that's getting into heavy reflection.

Comment: @BrianS You couldn't dynamically add a local variable to the current context.  You could create a new context that has dynamic local variables in it, which is somewhat different.  The former would require mutating the stack for the current frame, which shouldn't be possible.

Comment: True, although I wouldn't be surprised if even _that_ were achievable via unsafe operations. (I don't touch `unsafe` though, unlike the reflection libraries, so I wouldn't know how to achieve it.) Of course, you still wouldn't be able to simply write the generated local variable(s) in the code, as the compiler wouldn't know what to do with them. You'd need more reflection to do anything with such a local variable were you to even get it created. Suffice it to say, using `Dictionary` is **much** faster, easier, safer, and uses less of your processor.

Comment: @BrianS My guess is there are only a small handful of people in the world capable of writing such a solution, if it is possible, and all of them know better than to actually do it, which is why I felt it wouldn't be helpful to bring it up.  It's an unnecessary temptation, "See that poisoned apple over there?  Doesn't it look tasty?  Please don't eat it while I go into the next room for a while."